# C9 IDE working with java buildpath

Tags: java, collaboration

Me and my friends are trying to collab on a java projects, so we found C9 IDE, and we found a small tutorial on how to set up java on it, but we are having many problems with it, Can someone help us figure out how to set the correct build path?

[image: Picture of our setup]

Here is the My Builder.build file:

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "mkdir -p $OUT_DIR; find $SRC_DIR -name \"*.java\" -print | xargs javac -sourcepath $SRC_DIR -d \"$OUT_DIR\"; echo '\\033[01;34mDone!\\033[00m'"
  ],
  "info": "\\033[01;34mBuilding\\033[00m \\033[01;31m$project_name\\033[00m",
  "env": {"OUT_DIR": "$project_path\\.bin", "CLASSPATH" : "$OUT_DIR:$CLASSPATH", "SRC_DIR": "src"},
  "selector": "source.java",
  "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

And here is the My Runner.run

```
{
  "cmd": [
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "echo $file | sed -r 's/.*\\/src\\///g' | sed -r 's/\\.java//g'  | sed -r 's/\\//\\./g' | xargs java"
  ],
  "info": "\\033[01;34mRunning\\033[00m \\033[01;31m$file_name\\033[00m\n",
  "env": {"OUT_DIR": "$project_path\\.bin", "CLASSPATH" : "$OUT_DIR:$CLASSPATH"},
  "selector": "source.java",
  "working_dir": "$project_path"
}
```

we are trying to get the src file to read so we can get the Main.class to be the class that it runs, any help with be must appreciated!

Comment: are you getting any error when you run it

Comment: @RiteshK when i try to build it, it says "Building phx javac: no source files

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
My Builder.build file:
     {
          "cmd": [
            "sh",
            "-c",
            "mkdir -p $OUT_DIR; find $SRC_DIR -name \"*.java\" -print | xargs javac -sourcepath $SRC_DIR -d \"$OUT_DIR\"; echo '\\033[01;34mDone!\\033[00m'"
          ],
          "info": "\\033[01;34mBuilding\\033[00m \\033[01;31m$project_name\\033[00m",
          "env": {"OUT_DIR": "$project_path\\java", "CLASSPATH" : "$OUT_DIR:$CLASSPATH", "SRC_DIR": "java"},
          "selector": "source.java",
          "working_dir": "$project_path"
        }

My Runner.run
    {
      "cmd": [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "echo $file | sed -r 's/.*\\/src\\/java\\///g' | sed -r 's/\\.java//g'  | sed -r 's/\\//\\./g' | xargs java"
      ],
      "info": "\\033[01;34mRunning\\033[00m \\033[01;31m$file_name\\033[00m\n",
      "env": {"OUT_DIR": "$project_path\\java", "CLASSPATH" : "$OUT_DIR:$CLASSPATH"},
      "selector": "source.java",
      "working_dir": "$project_path"
    }
```

Comment: still gives me, the javac: no source files , error when i try to build it, and when i run it, it says, Error: Could not find or load main class .home.ubuntu.workspace.src.Main.Class

Comment: make sure your class and filename are both titled the same name for eg HelloWorld

Comment: Make sure your src folder is in your main workspace folder so your file should be at /home/ubuntu/workspace/src/"filename".java.

Comment: @joejoethemonkey try renaming your file to some other name one word and remove the dot